# Issue with plotting uploaded CSV

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a dashboard using plotly/Dash that allows the user to upload a CSV file and then plot the results. I have borrowed from the examples in the dash [documentation](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload)
and tried to piece together an example that plots the graph but I get an error message which I've attached below.

My code is attached:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

graph_name = 'Time series plot'
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

colors = {
    "graphBackground": "#212529",
    "background": "#000000",
    "text": "#ffffff"
}
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),

    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
    dcc.Graph(id='new-hydrograph')
])

def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])
    if df.shape[1] == 4:

        df = df.iloc[2:]
        df.columns = ['Datetime', 'Depth (in)', 'Velocity (feet/sec)', 'Flow (MGD)']
    else:
        df.columns = ['Datetime', 'Rain (in)']

    return df


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
        return children

@app.callback(Output('new-hydrograph', 'figure'),
            [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
            Input('upload-data', 'filename')])

def plot_graph(contents, filename):

    df = parse_contents(contents, filename)


    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = df.date, 
        y = df['Depth (in)'],
        mode = 'lines',
        )
    return {
        'data': [trace1],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title = graph_name,
            plot_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"])
    }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
sk\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
h-0.39.0-py3.6.egg\dash\dash.py", line 1073, in dispatch
    response.set_data(self.callback_map[output]['callbac
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond
h-0.39.0-py3.6.egg\dash\dash.py", line 969, in add_conte
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\Documents\Atlanta\pressure_data
- Copy\app_1.py", line 93, in plot_graph
    df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\Documents\Atlanta\pressure_data
- Copy\app_1.py", line 50, in parse_contents
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Here's an example CSV

```
PRC-01   "Average=15min"     "QualityFlag=FALSE"     "QualityValue=FALSE"
DateTime     "MP1\DFINAL"    "MP1\VFINAL"    "MP1\QFINAL"
M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt  "inches"    "feet/sec"  "MGD"
1/1/2015 0:00   14.9748 3.69    7.976
1/1/2015 0:15   15.0504 3.64    7.934
1/1/2015 0:30   14.7672 3.79    8.047
1/1/2015 0:45   14.9844 3.68    7.97
1/1/2015 1:00   14.8416 3.52    7.53
1/1/2015 1:15   14.7108 3.55    7.497
```

Comment: Looks like your `list_of_contents` ( data in `upload-data` `contents`) is a `list` such, but expect a `string` type. I suggest you try to look inside (such as `print(list_of_contents)`). Maybe you need to choose one element from `list_of_contents` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several problems:

1. The error you gave us stems from using `multiple=True` in the upload field. This causes the callback function to receive lists instead of strings in the `contents, filename` variables. Setting to `False` will solve that error, and allow you to select only a single file for upload, as I assume you intend.
2. Your CSV is tab-delimited, so must include `delimiter='\t'` in your `pd.read_csv` call.
3. The callback function gets called once on page load even when no file is selected. In that case `contents, filename` are both `None`. I suggest checking this at the start of the callback function, before attempting to parse the input.
4. You used the wrong name for the date column. You need `df['Datetime']`, according to the columns you define in `parse_contents`.

Points 3 and 4 are taken care of in the revised function below. Don't forget to take care of points 1 and 2.

```
@app.callback(Output('new-hydrograph', 'figure'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def plot_graph(contents, filename):
    fig = {
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title=graph_name,
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"])
    }

    if contents:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=df['Datetime'],
            y=df['Depth (in)'],
            mode='lines',
        )
        fig['data'] = [trace1]

    return fig
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Now, when I try to upload the second time, I get an error `- Copy\app_1.py", line 84, in update_output
    zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names)]
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\Documents\Atlanta\pressure_data_anal
- Copy\app_1.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
    parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
  File "C:\Users\hvkumar\Documents\Atlanta\pressure_data_anal
- Copy\app_1.py", line 50, in parse_contents
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. Is that something to do with multiple file uploads?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I tried with two slightly different CSV files. Try printing `contents` inside `parse_contents` before the split command.